# How to fix a Gulp compilation error of "Task function must be specified"?

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation

I'm setting up Silverstriper frame work with ZURB Foundation. I have tried to compile my gulp file, but I have this error. I have already installed Gulp locally and CLI.

[image]

**This is my gulp version**

```
C:\Users\ss-dk13\Work\sample-site>gulp -v
[11:38:15] CLI version 2.0.1
[11:38:15] Local version 4.0.0
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the content of your gulpfile?

Comment: If you're using gulp 4, make sure you're following gulp 4 docs — there's breaking changes in the way tasks are defined. For example, if you're doing something like `gulp.task('taskA', ['taskB'])`, then you're doing it the gulp 3 way -- in gulp 4 you'd need to use `gulp.task('taskA', gulp.series('taskB'))`.

Comment: Yeh,I Updated my gulp version Then used _npm install natives@1.1.6 --save-dev_